# How to get abstract and thumbnail of a Wikipedia article from article DBPedia?

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

I am new to SPARQL. With this query, I can get the birthName of Ernest Hemingway:

```
select distinct ?birthName
where {
  ?person a dbpedia-owl:Person .
  ?person dbpprop:birthName ?birthName .
  FILTER (regex(?birthName, "Ernest Miller Hemingway"))
} 
LIMIT 1
```

Is there a way I can get the wikipedia abstract/introduction and thumbnail of Ernest Hemingway with DBPedia?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, the best way to start querying DBpedia if you already have an idea what you're looking for is to look at the page for the resource that you're interested in.  In this case, you want

- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Ernest_Hemingway, which redirects to
- http://dbpedia.org/page/Ernest_Hemingway

On that page, you'll see that the property relating a resource to its abstract is `dbpedia-owl:abstract`, and the thumbnail or image is `dbpedia-owl:thumbnail`.  Thus, you want a query like the following (which you can run on the [DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql)).  I've taken the liberty of restricting the results to just the English language abstract.

```sql
prefix dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

select ?abstract ?thumbnail where { 
  dbpedia:Ernest_Hemingway dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract ;
                           dbpedia-owl:thumbnail ?thumbnail .
  filter(langMatches(lang(?abstract),"en"))
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=prefix%20dbpedia%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0Aprefix%20dbpedia-owl%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20%3Fabstract%20%3Fthumbnail%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3AErnest_Hemingway%20dbpedia-owl%3Aabstract%20%3Fabstract%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3Athumbnail%20%3Fthumbnail%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%28langMatches%28lang%28%3Fabstract%29%2C%22en%22%29%29%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: @Ashesh That's because DBpedia's endpoint changed their predefined namespaces from dbpedia and dbpedia-owl to dbr and dbo.  I've updated the query so that it works again.

Comment: This was the problem due to which I ended up asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775721/how-to-query-a-particular-dbpedia-resource-page-for-multiple-entities. I did take the effort but much of the examples I came across were outdated. Now I use http://prefix.cc/ .