# How to query a particular DBpedia Resource/Page for multiple entities?

Tags: java, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I have links to a number of DBpedia pages like:
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harry_Potter
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Twilight_(series)
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Bible
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Manga

I would like to get the Abstract and Thumbnail entities for each one of them.

I can get them individually using:

- For Abstract:

  ```
  PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
  PREFIX res: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
  PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
  PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
  SELECT ?label
  WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harry_Potter>
            dbo:abstract ?label . FILTER (lang(?label) = \'en\')}
  ```
- For Thumbnail:

  ```
  PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
  PREFIX res: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
  PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
  PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
  SELECT ?thumbnail
  WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harry_Potter>
            dbo:thumbnail ?thumbnail}
  ```

Is it possible to combine the above two queries into a single one. I am very new to SPARQL and couldn't get [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931728/how-to-get-abstract-and-thumbnail-of-a-wikipedia-article-from-article-dbpedia) to work.

Additionally, is there a better way to query than my current approach?

Comment: You can combine the triple patterns into one query, sure. And what do you mean by better?

Comment: How do i combine them? and by better I mean more optimized manner

Comment: In the simplest case, just put both triple patterns in the same query,  each ending with a dot `.` That's all. In your example there not much space for optimization as it is too simple. If you want to write more compact SPARQL queries, you could have a look at the TURTLE syntax which is basically how you can write the triple patterns in SPARQL.

Comment: Thanks @AKSW I have got it working.

Comment: This seems to show a lack of research effort: browsing even any of the recent sparql questions on Stack Overflow would show plenty of examples of exactly what you're asking for. So would just about any sparql tutorial, as does the w3c'so sparql specification, which is full of examples.

Comment: As mentioned in the question itself, I did go through the site before posting. Have a look at the second last line of my question. The example that I saw was not correct (http://stackoverflow.com/a/19934416/2534513). I also came across W3C examples at https://www.w3.org/2009/Talks/0615-qbe/ but couldn't understand much of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it's possible to combine them, the trivial way to do it would be just to concatenate the bodies of the two `WHERE`s and adjust the `SELECT` accordingly:

```sql
SELECT ?label ?thumbnail
WHERE {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harry_Potter> dbo:abstract ?label . 
    FILTER (lang(?label) = 'en')
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harry_Potter> dbo:thumbnail ?thumbnail .
}
```

If you want to be more succinct, you can combine two triples with the same subject using `;`:

```sql
SELECT ?label ?thumbnail
WHERE {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Harry_Potter>
        dbo:abstract ?label ; 
        dbo:thumbnail ?thumbnail .
    FILTER (lang(?label) = 'en')
}
```

And since you defined the `res:` prefix, you can use that to shorten the URI:

```sql
SELECT ?label ?thumbnail
WHERE {
    res:Harry_Potter
        dbo:abstract ?label ; 
        dbo:thumbnail ?thumbnail .
    FILTER (lang(?label) = 'en')
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried the last snippet but it fails for certain urls like book-http://dbpedia.org/resource/Twilight_(series).

Comment: [`res:Twilight_\(series\)` should work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31385432/41071) for that, but it seems it doesn't on the Virtuoso endpoint. So you will have to use the full URL for that.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I had tried escaping the characters, still it didn't work. Will settle for URL.